# Validate PCRE in Java

Tags: java, regex, validation, pcre

Given a string, how can I validate the contents are a valid PCRE within Java? I don't want to use the regex in any way within Java, just validate its contents.

[java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is almost good enough, but its javadoc points out how it differs from Perl.

In detail, there's a system with 3 relevant components:

1. Component A - Generates, among other things, Perl-compliant regular expressions (PCREs) to be evaluated at runtime by some other component capable of executing PCREs (component C). What's "generated" here may be coming from a human.
2. Component B - Validates that data generated by component A and, if valid, shuttles it over to the runtime (component C).
3. Component C - Some runtime that evaluates PCREs. This could be a Perl VM, a native process using the [PCRE library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html), etc., or something else that can compile/execute a Perl-compliant regular expression.

Now, component B is implemented in Java. As mentioned above, it needs to **validate** a string potentially containing a PCRE, but does **not** need to execute it.

How could we do that?

One option would be something like:

```
public static boolean isValidPCRE(String str) {
    try {
        Pattern.compile(str);
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem is that `java.util.regex.Pattern` is designed to work with a regular expression syntax that is not exactly Perl-compliant. The javadoc makes that quite clear.

So, given a string, how can I validate the contents are a valid PCRE within Java?

Note: There are some differences between [libPCRE](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) and Perl, but they are pretty minor. To a certain degree, that is true of Java's syntax as well. However, the question still stands.

Comment: You'll have to either write a parser for the PCRE regex grammar (or use [an existing one](https://github.com/bkiers/pcre-parser)), or use the PCRE library directly through JNE for instance (or call a Perl script). Beware that boost::regex doesn't support the full Perl syntax though.

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me :) Can you point me towards documentation with more details about Boost.Regex not supporting full Perl syntax. I didn't see that in the library documentation, but probably missed it. More generally, that seems to be the case everywhere. I think my question now is more validating the string contents are some regex subset supported universally.

Comment: For instance [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) says that `(*MARK)` is not supported. Oh, and beware of `(?{`...`})` and `(??{`...`})` if you use Perl, those can execute embedded code. There's no such thing as a "regex subset supported universally", believe me :) or if you need convincing, go [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refbasic.html) and take a look at the various pages and options.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that's the case, but I take your broader point. There is tons of variability here, even on some pretty basic stuff. I'm leaning towards settling on the C++ regex library (std::regex perhaps) and using JNI to validate the string within Java. Thanks for your help @ Lucas Trzesniewski.